How to send a navigation goal in the local odom frame with Nav2?
I’m trying to send a goal relative to my robot base (eg. to get it to go 1.5m forward and 1.0m to the right). My plan is to first transform the pose in the base_link frame to the odom frame, then publish it as a goal for the planner and controller to compute required the paths/velocities. I want to be able to send navigation goals in both the map and odom frames without having to re-launch the navigation.
However, when I publish a goal in the odom frame, the planner server transforms it into the map frame. I believe the planner server converts it into whatever the global costmap's global frame is, which is map. The actual position/orientation of the goal looks right, it's just that since it is all in the map frame, it makes the goal susceptible to changes in the map -> odom transform.
ros2 topic pub --once /goal_pose geometry_msgs/msg/PoseStamped "{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: 'odom'}, pose: {position: {x: -1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}}"

Additionally, when I publish a pose in the odom frame, I get this error whenever the robot gets within ~0.3-0.5m of the goal.
[planner_server-3] [ERROR] [1734345813.329039804] [transformPoseInTargetFrame]: Extrapolation Error looking up target frame: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1734345803.552809 but the earliest data is at time 1734345804.141072, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]
[planner_server-3] 
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1734345813.329087731] [planner_server]: Could not transform the start or goal pose in the costmap frame
[planner_server-3] [WARN] [1734345813.329129275] [planner_server]: [compute_path_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1734345813.345524796] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap

I see from this issue that it's possible to change the global frame of the behavior tree nodes at run-time but haven't found a way to do so in either the ComputePathToPose or NavigateToPose behavior tree nodes.
Here's what I have tried:
Tried to change /bt_navigator and /behavior_server global_frame parameter to odom

I used a service call like the one below to do this, and for both I got a response saying I cannot undeclare a statically typed parameter.
ros2 service call /bt_navigator/set_parameters rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters "{parameters: [ {name: 'global_frame', value: {string_value: 'odom'}} ]}"
response: rcl_interfaces.srv.SetParameters_Response(results=[rcl_interfaces.msg.SetParametersResult(successful=False, reason='cannot undeclare an statically typed parameter')])

Edit: Why I want to navigate in odom frame
I’m looking to navigate relative to my robot base. I want to navigate in the odom frame because it’s “used for locally-consistent representations of distances” according to the Setting Up Transforms page in the Nav2 docs. This local consistency is what I want when navigating relative to my robot base. I don’t want the global localization errors to affect this movement relative to the robot, which would happen if I publish it in the map frame.

You can use TF2 transform library to transform a PoseStamped message from one frame to another. With this you can transform it to map frame and then give as a goal.
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped newPose = tfBuffer->transform( pose, "map", tf2::durationFromSec( 0.5 ) );
Note: tfBuffer is an object of type tf2_ros::Buffer.
Arguments:
pose: The input PoseStamped object whose frame needs to be transformed.
"map": The name of the target frame to which the pose will be transformed.
tf2::durationFromSec(0.5): A timeout duration (0.5 seconds). If the transform is not available within this time, the method may throw an exception.

Thanks for your reply! Maybe I wasn’t that clear. I know how to transform a PoseStamped message from base link to another frame (eg. map or odom). My problem is that when I do publish a goal pose in the odom frame, the planner converts it into the map frame, which can be noisy relative to my base_link. My application is similar to docking, in that I want to decouple the localization error from the robot movement. Any idea how to achieve this without specifically using the Nav2 Docking package?

Why are you publishing a goal pose in the odom frame? You can transform it before you publish...

And if you want your application is similar to docking, are you assuming there is no obstacle between the robot and the goal pose? If so, you can calculate the angle between your robot and the goal pose and turn your robot to the angle and go straight.

I’m not assuming that there are no obstacles, I’m hoping to have some form of obstacle avoidance and path planning. I edited the question to explain why I want the goal pose in the odom frame.
